# How to load policy saved with triggers.PolicySavedModelTrigger in tf Agent

Tags: tensorflow, tf-agent

I ran the SAC training code as shown in this demo [1]. When training finishes, inside the `policies` folder, there are a few folders: `checkpoints`, `collect_policy`, `greedy_policy`, `policy`.

I would like to load the policy from disk for evaluation. From which folder should I load the policy?

How should I load the policy from disk?

I include the folder hierarchy in [2].

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/7_SAC_minitaur_tutorial

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIr7W.png